# WCF ProtocolException receiving html

Tags: wcf

I am getting the below error while accesssing method from WCF to DotNet

```
The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<html>
    <head>
        <title>Runtime Error</title>
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/ORSXMLWCFServiceNew' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </'.
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the full response

Comment: You can also sometimes put the URL you're hitting in a web browser and see the HTML error.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way how to get full response, not just useless 1024 bytes...

```
using (var client = new Service1Client())
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(client.DoWork());
    }
    catch (ProtocolException e)
    {
        var webException = e.InnerException as WebException;

        var responseString = webException.ExtractResponseString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseText))
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

where the following helper method is used

```
public static string ExtractResponseString(this WebException webException)
{
    if (webException == null || webException.Response == null)
        return null;

    var responseStream = webException.Response.GetResponseStream() as MemoryStream;

    if (responseStream == null)
        return null;

    var responseBytes = responseStream.ToArray();

    var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    return responseString;
}
```

See my blog for more details http://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2012/09/28/wcf-protocolexception/

Comment: Not working for me because e.InnerException is null.  Any ideas?  I am using .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an error on your WCF service, the best way to go about fixing it (after checking your code for anything obvious) would be to get some error logging working on the WCF service and check for any exceptions in the logs.

These might help:

[Adding logging to WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx)

[Creating a logging class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569547/logging-errors-in-wcf-nothing-being-stored-in-log-file-when-exception-is-being)